# PHP Cookie entering two blank spaces

Tags: php, forms, validation, cookies

I have a registration form and I am trying to create cookies that will keep the users data entered should they try to submit the form with a validation error. The cookie is doing this but it is also causing additional problems.

When the form is loaded the cookie seems to be entered two blank spaces in the form field and when if the user submits the form with validation errors it keeps the users information but inserts two blank spaces in front of their details. What is causing this?

HTML Form:

```
  <p class="error" id="jsFirstError">
    <?php
      if(isset($_COOKIE['firstNameErr'])) {
        echo $_COOKIE["firstNameErr"];
      }
    ?>
  </p>
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" id="firstNameField" autofocus="autofocus" value="
  <?php 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['firstNameEntry'])) {
      echo $_COOKIE['firstNameEntry'];
    }
    ?>"><br /><br />
```

Validation and cookie:

```
  if(empty($fname)) {
      $error = true;
      setcookie("firstNameErr", "Please enter your First Name.", time()+1, '/');
  } else if(!ctype_alpha($fname)) {
      $error = true;
      setcookie("firstNameErr", "Only letters are accepted, please re-enter your First Name.", time()+1, '/');
  } else {
      setcookie("firstNameEntry", $fname, time()+1, '/');
  }
```

Comment: try to omit the space between your p element and the <?php start tag then do the same for the value of the firstNameField as i can see you have one space before the <?php tag and this will cause the extra space you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a registration form and I am trying to create cookies that will keep the users data entered should they try to submit the form with a validation error.

Why would you want to use cookies for this?

The script that the data has been send to already has all the necessary info – so it’s more than easy to output it directly from there again, without the use of cookies.

> When the form is loaded the cookie seems to be entered two blank spaces in the form field and when if the user submits the form with validation errors it keeps the users information but inserts two blank spaces in front of their details. What is causing this?

The white space that you insert into your HTML by having your PHP code that is outputting the values span over multiple lines with spaces before the `<?php` tag.

And btw., you are opening your page up to possible XSS attacks by not escaping data you are putting into the context HTML properly.

Comment: How would you go about outputting it?

Comment: Without whitespace between the `"` limiting the content of the value attribute and the actual data you want to put inside it, and with proper HTML escaping …